# Remove Name and owner in CRM Dynamics

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have created a form for cheque entries. But when i create the form "name" and "owner" field are compulsory and it does not allow to remove either. Any suggestions really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Owner` attribute is inside the form because the `Ownership` when you created the entity was set to `User or Team` instead of `Organization`.

[image]

If you create the entity to be as `Organization`, you will not have the `Owner` field BUT you are limited to define the roles on this entity, you can't define for example to make users from a business unit to access only to their records, if a user has a read privilege will be at Organization level (meaning he will be able to read all the records)

Regarding the `Name` field it's the primary attribute of the entity, from your screenshot looks like you have a field called `ChequeNumber`, you can delete that field and rename the label of `Name` field to `Cheque Number` (if the field type is `Single Type of Text`) or when you create the entity you define correctly the primary attribute:

[image]